# How do i print a positional argument

Tags: python-3.x, arguments

I have this example code and nee to print out e.g. the second argument position alone, how do i do it?

```
def fun(a, b, c):
     d = locals()
     e = d
     print (e)
     print (locals())

fun(None, 2, None)
```

Comment: my edit button is not working for some unknown reason. i wish to edit this Q to read; call for an argument position such as fun[1](position 2 etc). the way u can call a string character position

Answer (score 0):

`print(b)` ... or I do not understand the question.

**Update:** If you mean to know the names of the arguments, you may want to use the standard module named `inspect`. Try the following:

```
#!python3
import inspect

def fun(a, b, c):
     d = locals()
     e = d
     print (e)
     print (locals())

     # Here for observing from inside.
     argspec = inspect.getfullargspec(fun)
     print(argspec.args)
     for arg in argspec.args:
         print('argument', repr(arg), '=', repr(d[arg])) 

     # You can use indexing of the arg names if you like. Then the name
     # is used for looking in locals() -- here you have it in d.
     args = argspec.args
     print(d[args[0]])    
     print(d[args[1]])    
     print(d[args[2]])    

fun(None, 2, None)

# Here for observing from outside.
argspec = inspect.getfullargspec(fun)
print(argspec.args)

for n, arg in enumerate(argspec.args, 1):
    print('argument', n, 'is named', repr(arg))
```

You should observe:

```
{'a': None, 'b': 2, 'c': None}
{'d': {...}, 'e': {...}, 'a': None, 'b': 2, 'c': None}
['a', 'b', 'c']
argument 'a' = None
argument 'b' = 2
argument 'c' = None
None
2
None
['a', 'b', 'c']
argument 1 is named 'a'
argument 2 is named 'b'
argument 3 is named 'c'
```

See the doc http://docs.python.org/3.3/library/inspect.html#inspect.getfullargspec

Comment: Thanks , i need a code like: for arguments in fun[1](position 2 etc). I want a way to all the position and not the argument